# How to combine elements of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Here is a sample program I am using.

```
while(split.good()){
            split >>first;
            split >>second;
            word=first + second;
            //cout<< static_cast<char> (word)<<endl;
            vec.push_back(static_cast<char> (word));

        }
```

first and second are int values.
So I want to combine the elements of the vector to make a complete word.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you should heed [@AliciaBytes' advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36928719/4143855) about your `while` loop.

To combine all your elements in your `vector` into a single word, you can use the [following `std::string` constructor that takes two iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

> template< class InputIt >
> basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last,
> const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

Pass in a beginning and end `iterator` of your `vector`:

```
const std::string s{std::begin(vec), std::end(vec)};
```

This will add each element of `vec` into the `std::string`. Alternatively, you could use a `for` loop:

```
std::string s;
for (auto c : vec)
{
    // Add each character to the string
    s += c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off change your loop, checking for `.eof()` or `.good()` is a bad idea, see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1942027) for more info. Instead use:

```
while(split >> first && split >> second)
```

to check that reading the values actually worked.

**I misunderstood the question so the below answer isn't really what was wanted, check [@Tas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36928809/1942027) instead.**

Next I if I understand correctly you want to convert the integers into a string? It's a bit unclear but have a look at `std::to_string()`. Maybe you want something like:

```
while(split >> first && split >> second) {
    word = first + second;
    vec.push_back(std::to_string(word));
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion, "word" is really a char value, its just a bad name I gave for the char value you get from the added integer values after they are changed to char. so when that while is over what I get is a vector of char elements. I wanted to know how I can combine the char elements of the vector to make a word. sort of like
vec = {'h' , 'e' , 'l' , 'l' , 'o' };
and I want a string "hello" from the vector vec. I hope this makes sense and thank you for your input.

Comment: @FreA guess I misunderstood what you wanted to do. Anyways, @Tas answer is exactly what you want to do, just gonna leave this answer as it is for the `while` part of it.